# How can i change a href link in 3 seconds?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```html
<a class="fr" name="fr style="margin-top:9px;float: left;" href="http://www.example.org/" rel="home" target="_blank">
 <img style="width: 42.4em;
    height: 7.5em;" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample.gif" alt="sample"/>
</a>
```

I want to change the a href link in 3 seconds. That is, in the first 3 seconds, it should redirect to "Site 1" on click. In the next 3 seconds, the link should redirect to "Site 2" when someone click on. And like wise there should be 4 links. After the 4th link, it should come back to the first link. Can someone please help me do it with jQuery?

I have tried this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("a.fr").attr("href", "http://google.com");
</script>
```

But i want 4 links which should get replaced in 3 seconds each

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SetInterval to use a function every X milliseconds would work.
From [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) :

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

You just have to store your link in an array, and use the number of iterations % 4 so that you only loop with : 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3

```
var hrefs = ['link1.com','link2.com','link3.com','link4.com'];
var iterations = 0;

function changeLink() {
    $(".yourElement").attr("href", hrefs[iterations%4])
    iterations++;
}

var linkChange = setInterval(changeLink, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-href-attribute-of-a-hyperlink-using-jquery.php) may be this will help you and if you need to change the link use **setInterval** function that is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

May it can help you. You can use setTimeout() for timing and attr() for change the url or link.

Check it out

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     $("#w3s").attr("href", "https://codepen.io/indeveloper/")
    },3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">Check your link</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>

</body>
</html>
```